# Ajax with coldfusion8

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I am very new to Ajax technique

Is there any site or online documents where I can learn from basics of Ajax with coldfusion?

Thanks-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using Ajax UI Components and Features](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/ajaxui_1.html)

[Using Ajax Data and Development Features](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/ajaxdata_01.html)

Answer (score 1):

And also Ben Forta

http://www.forta.com/blog/

(search for "coldfusion ajax tutorial", there's a series of 7)

and Ray Camden's blog

http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [video](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/using-ajax-to-retrieve-data-from-coldfusion/) tutorial I did for Adobe.TV on the built-in AJAX functionality in ColdFusion.